# How to use bitops.h in user space

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, bit

I have this program where  I need to do some bit operations using the test_and_set_bit function found in bitops.h file. How can I include this file using `#include<linux/bitops.h>` in my `C` file. It doesn't seem to find it even though I could find it in the kernel source.

Is it because it is not allowed to include in the user space program. Suggestions?

I am using `#include<linux/bitops.h>` then compiling using `gcc myfile.c`.

It shows no such file or directory for the bitops.h file. I could find it under the kernel directory though

Comment: I would just suggest using gcc [atomic builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins).

Comment: @David. Could you please elaborate. I didn't get it

Comment: There is a full set of atomic bit operations built into GCC. For example [__sync_fetch_and_or](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlc121.aix.doc%2Fcompiler_ref%2Fbif_gcc_atomic_fetch_or.html) atomically fetches the current value and does a logical OR to the current value to get the new value.

Comment: @David. How do I use them. Do I need to include any headers

Comment: They're built into the compiler. There's nothing special you need to do.

Comment: @David. Also isn't it at all possible to use test_and_set_bit function in the bitops.h file from user space

Comment: Why would you want to? Those aren't as efficient as the operations built into the compiler and they only work on a single type. The built ins are maximally optimized and type independent.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz isn't it overkill to use the atomic built-ins to just do bitwise operations?

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca: Not if they need to be atomic. For non-atomic operations, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with `bitops.h`. It can produce undefined behavior from well defined sources.

For example, for the [C/C++ language (see section 5.8)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2798.pdf), a shift cannot be negative, cannot be equal to the length of the word, and cannot exceed the length of the word. That means a 32-bit value can only be shifted [0,31] inclusive.

In the above example, anything other than [0,31] is "undefined". I believe the compiler is free to do what it wants for undefined code, including removal of the offending code, calling `abort()`, or shitting all over itself.

Many programs abuse shifts and rotates. A great way to test/check is to use John Regehr and Peng Li's [Integer Overflow Checker (IOC)](http://embed.cs.utah.edu/ioc/). Its easy to build Clang with the functionality (`-fcatch-undefined-ansic-behavior`), so the tools are available to check these things.

With that said, below is the code from the 3.8 Kernel's `<linux\bitops.h>` (downloaded FEB-19-2013). If a programmer sends in a shift size of `0` (legal), `<linux\bitops.h>` will create illegal code due to `(word << (32 - shift))` (et al).

When I pointed it out on the kernel mailing list, I was told "the kernel doesn't try to be fully standard conformant." Part of the problem with the kernel appears to be Torvalds and his ["GCC is crap"](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Kernel/2006-11/msg08325.html) attitude - he's too l33t to do things correctly and use the tools such as static analysis, and some of his fellow developers have the same arrogance.

```
/**
 * rol64 - rotate a 64-bit value left
 * @word: value to rotate
 * @shift: bits to roll
 */
static inline __u64 rol64(__u64 word, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (word << shift) | (word >> (64 - shift));
}

/**
 * ror64 - rotate a 64-bit value right
 * @word: value to rotate
 * @shift: bits to roll
 */
static inline __u64 ror64(__u64 word, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (word >> shift) | (word << (64 - shift));
}

/**
 * rol32 - rotate a 32-bit value left
 * @word: value to rotate
 * @shift: bits to roll
 */
static inline __u32 rol32(__u32 word, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (word << shift) | (word >> (32 - shift));
}

/**
 * ror32 - rotate a 32-bit value right
 * @word: value to rotate
 * @shift: bits to roll
 */
static inline __u32 ror32(__u32 word, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (word >> shift) | (word << (32 - shift));
}

/**
 * rol16 - rotate a 16-bit value left
 * @word: value to rotate
 * @shift: bits to roll
 */
static inline __u16 rol16(__u16 word, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (word << shift) | (word >> (16 - shift));
}

/**
 * ror16 - rotate a 16-bit value right
 * @word: value to rotate
 * @shift: bits to roll
 */
static inline __u16 ror16(__u16 word, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (word >> shift) | (word << (16 - shift));
}

/**
 * rol8 - rotate an 8-bit value left
 * @word: value to rotate
 * @shift: bits to roll
 */
static inline __u8 rol8(__u8 word, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (word << shift) | (word >> (8 - shift));
}

/**
 * ror8 - rotate an 8-bit value right
 * @word: value to rotate
 * @shift: bits to roll
 */
static inline __u8 ror8(__u8 word, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (word >> shift) | (word << (8 - shift));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change `#include<linux/bitops.h>` to `#include <asm/bitops.h>`.

If the problem remains, you must use `gcc myfile.cpp -I"your linux directory"` to tell `gcc` where your kernel file is.

Comment: you use `gcc -I` but it still doesn't find the linux/bitops.h?

Comment: bitops.h is normally not installed as userspace headers under /usr/include. Using it is not as easy as specifying a single -I argument, as many kernel only headers require the kernel build machinery to set up required paths and so on

Comment: +1 to @brandy. ASM is the way to go to avoid "undefined statements" and "illegal programs" due to C/C++ requirements (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I tried including a variety of kernel headers from **/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)** (installed during kernel build) using the `-I kernel_header_path` search path but all require one or more other kernel headers.  It looks like **./include/linux/bitops.h** is the suggested include file for all arch-specific bit ops.

So, I agree with @nos: using kernel code for user-space bit twiddling is not easy.  However, the arch-specific assembler in the **arch/../include/asm/bitops.h** can be lifted for user-space bit ops.

OTOH, it's probably not worth the development effort versus writing a small generic bit op include file to achieve the same result.